# Data structure for continuous additions and cheap deletions

Tags: java, qt, data-structures, parallel-processing, gnuplot

I am reading this [blog post](http://www.gnuplotting.org/animation-iii-video-revisited/) about making animations with Gnuplot and Cairo -terminal which algo's plan is simply

- to save png-images to working directory, and
- to save latest the video to working directory.

I would like to have something more such that the user can also browse the images real time when the images are being converted:

### Data-parallelism model - data structure regularly arranged in an array

- to give the user some list in some interface which the user can browse by arrow buttons
- in this interface, new images are being added to the end of the list
- the user can also remove bad images from the stream in real time

which may work well in *Data parallelism model* of Parallel programming i.e. a data set regularly structured in an array. 
The operations (additions, deletions) can operate on this data, but independently on distinct processes.

Let's assume that there is no need for efficient searches for simplicity in Version 1. 
However, if you come with a model which can do that also, I am happy to consider it - let's call it Version 2.

I think a list is not a good data structure here because of the wanted opportunity for deletions and continuous easy addition to the end of the data structure. 
The data structure *stack* is not going to work either because of deletions. 
I think some sort of *tree* data structure can work because of rather cheap deletions and cheap search there. 
However, a simple array in the Data-parallelism model can be sufficient.

### Languages

I think Java is a good option here because of parallelism. 
However, any language and pseudocode are good too.

### Frontend

I have an intuition that requirements for such a system in the frontend should be qT as a terminal emulator.

**What is a better data structure for cheap deletions and continuous additions to the end?**

Comment: You might want to state what language you want this in.

Comment: I don't understand why you don't want to use lists. Deletion of current item and addition to the end is exactly what lists do well (at least `QList` do). Regarding search, what exactly is data for search and what should search engine be able to do? (e.g. exact match of some string or even substring.)

Comment: @PavelStrakhov You may be right in some places. However, I think there is some demand for parallel programming here in implementation which sets a restriction, since a continuous stream and its visualization and its edition. However, I may be wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java `LinkedList` seems to be the thing you could use for version 1. you can use its single param `add()` to append to the list in constant time. if by "real-time" you mean when the image is in user's display and thus pointed to somehow, can delete them in constant time as well. 
optimum use of memory and no re-instantiation as you'd have with an `Arraylist`. 
any doubly linked list implemented on objects (as opposed to an array) would do.

your second version isn't clear enough.

Comment: Good start! I left out the version 2 now for simplicity. I think Data parallelism model can be a good way here to go such that a regularly ordered array can be enough.